# Should I include distinct in this JPQL query?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

#### Background

I have seen multiple answers and questions here on SO and in many popular blogs about the necessity of the `distinct` keyword in JPQL `JOIN FETCH` queries and about the `PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH` query hint.

For example, see these two questions

- [How does DISTINCT work when using JPA and Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346181/how-does-distinct-work-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate)
- [Select DISTINCT on JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42830497/select-distinct-on-jpa)

and these blog posts

- [The best way to use the JPQL DISTINCT keyword with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpql-distinct-jpa-hibernate)
- [The DISTINCT pass-through Hibernate Query Hint](https://in.relation.to/2016/08/04/introducing-distinct-pass-through-query-hint/)
- [Hibernate Tips: How To Apply DISTINCT to Your JPQL But Not Your SQL Query](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-apply-distinct-to-jpql-but-not-sql-query/)

#### What I am missing

Now my problem is that I cannot fully understand when exactly the `distinct` keyword must be included in the JPQL query. More specifically, if it depends on which method is used to execute the query (`getResultList` or `getSingleResult`).

The following is an example to clarify what I mean.

Everything I am writing from now on was tested on Ubuntu Linux 18.04, with Java 8, Hibernate 5.4.13 and an in-memory H2 database (version 1.4.200).

Suppose I have a `Department` entity which has a **lazy** bidirectional one to many relationship with a `DepartmentDirector` entity:

```java
// Department.java
@Entity
public class Department {
    // ...
    private Set<DepartmentDirector> directors;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public Set<DepartmentDirector> getDirectors() {
        return directors;
    }
    // ...
}

// DepartmentDirector.java
@Entity
public class DepartmentDirector {
    // ...
    private Department department

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "department_fk")
    public Department getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Suppose that my database currently contains one department (`department1`) and two directors associated with it.

Now I want to retrieve the department by its uuid (the primary key), along with all its directors. This can be done with the following `JOIN FETCH` JPQL query:

```java
String query = "select department from Department department left join fetch "
             + "department.directors where department.uuid = :uuid";
```

As the preceding query uses a `join fetch` with a child collection, I expected it to return two duplicated departments when issued: however this only happens when using the query with the `getResultList` method and not when using the `getSingleResult` method. This is somehow reasonable, but I have found that the Hibernate implementation of `getSingleResult` uses `getResultList` behind the curtains so I expected a `NonUniqueResultException` to be thrown.

I also briefly went through JPA 2.2 specification but no distinction in treating the duplicates between the two methods is mentioned, and every code sample concerning this issue uses the `getResultList` method.

#### Conclusion

In my example I found out that `JOIN FETCH` queries executed with `getSingleResult` do not suffer the duplicated entities problem explained in the resources I linked in the section **Background**.

If the above claim would be correct, it would mean that the same `JOIN FETCH` query would need `distinct` if executed with `getResultList`, but would not need it when executed with `getSingleResult`.

I need someone to explain me if this is expected or if I misunderstood something.

---

#### Appendix

Results of the two queries:

1. Query ran with the `getResultList` method. I get two duplicated departments as expected (*this was done just to test the behaviour of the query, `getSingleResult` should be used instead for this*):

   ```java
   List<Department> resultList = entityManager.createQuery(query, Department.class)
           .setParameter("uuid", department1.getUuid())
           .getResultList();

   assertThat(resultList).containsExactly(department1, department1); // passes
   ```
2. Query ran with the `getSingleResult` method. I would expect the same duplicated departments to be retrieved, and thus a `NonUniqueResultException` to be thrown. Instead, a single department is retrieved and everything works nice:

   ```java
   Department singleResult = entityManager.createQuery(query, Department.class)
           .setParameter("uuid", department1.getUuid())
           .getSingleResult();

   assertThat(singleResult).isEqualTo(department1); // passes
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question.

First of all let me point out that `getSingleResult()` was meant for queries that *due to their nature* always return a single result (meaning: mostly aggregate queries like `SELECT SUM(e.id) FROM Entity e`). A query that you *think*, based on some business domain-specific rule, should return a single result, does not really qualify.

That being said, the JPA Spec states that `getSingleResult()` should throw `NonUniqueResultException` when the query returns more than one result:

> The `NonUniqueResultException` is thrown by the persistence provider when `Query.getSingleResult` or `TypedQuery.getSingleResult` is invoked and there is more than one result from the query. This exception will not cause the current transaction, if one is active, to be marked for rollback.

However, looking at the Hibernate implementation:

```
    @Override
    public R getSingleResult() {
        try {
            final List<R> list = list();
            if ( list.size() == 0 ) {
                throw new NoResultException( "No entity found for query" );
            }
            return uniqueElement( list );
        }
        catch ( HibernateException e ) {
            if ( getProducer().getFactory().getSessionFactoryOptions().isJpaBootstrap() ) {
                throw getExceptionConverter().convert( e );
            }
            else {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }

    public static <R> R uniqueElement(List<R> list) throws NonUniqueResultException {
        int size = list.size();
        if ( size == 0 ) {
            return null;
        }
        R first = list.get( 0 );
        for ( int i = 1; i < size; i++ ) {
            if ( list.get( i ) != first ) {
                throw new NonUniqueResultException( list.size() );
            }
        }
        return first;
    }
```

it turns out Hibernate's interpretation of 'more than one result' seems to be 'more than one **unique** result'.

In fact, I tested your scenario with all JPA providers, and it turns out that:

- Hibernate does indeed return duplicates from `getResultList()`, but does *not* throw the exception due to the peculiar way `getSingleResult()` is implemented
- EclipseLink is the only one that does not suffer from the duplicate result bug in `getResultList()` and consequently, `getSingleResult()` does *not* throw an exception, either (to me, this behaviour is only logical, but as it turns out, it is all a matter of interpretation)
- OpenJPA and DataNucleus both return duplicate results from `getResultList()` and throw an exception from `getSingleResult()`

Tl;DR

> I need someone to explain me if this is expected or if I misunderstood something.

It really boils down to how you interpret the specification

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Now I can see that I was looking at the wrong source code (`org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.getSingleResult()`).