# Hibernate loads same entity multiple time with many to many relation ship and left join?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to load single Merchant entity with its Categories, and relationship between Merchant and Category is Many-To-Many. Also Category entity has also translations... So I wrote following code to retrieve data that I need from database:

```
Merchant merchant = queryFactory.selectFrom(QMerchant.merchant)
        .leftJoin(QMerchant.merchant.categories, QMerchantCategory.merchantCategory).fetchJoin()
        .leftJoin(QMerchantCategory.merchantCategory.translations, QMerchantCategoryTranslation.merchantCategoryTranslation).fetchJoin()
        .where(QMerchant.merchant.id.eq(merchantStore.getMerchant().getId()))
        .fetchOne();
```

However, what I get as a result is Merchant that has list of three categories (that are same) and each with three translation objects...

[image]

I can check in database that there is only one category in replationship with merchant that I am trying to load, and as you can see from the picture from JVM IDs that those are all same instances... Also following code gives same result:

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"categories", "categories.translations"})
Optional<Merchant> findWithCategoriesById(long id);
```

If add another translation then I will have merchant with four categories...

So how do I tell hibernate to load Merchant entity that has one category entity in the list (as it should have, because there is only one category associated with merchant), but I also need all translations to be loaded for that category, and if possible, to do it with one query, i can solve it with two queries, but i would like it to be only one... or if there is a better reason to have two queries to extract data from database...?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I include distinct in this JPQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63410722/should-i-include-distinct-in-this-jpql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Use `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` annotation with lazy fetch type method. A good post to read https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-lazy-eager-loading.

Comment: I am using FetchType.LAZY everywhere, it is not problem that i do not want to load, the problem is hibernate duplicates categories...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `categories` attribute is a list. You need to use a `Set` instead